# Blogger - data:post.snippet to replace data:blog.metaDescription for *:description

Tags: blogs, blogger

I am trying to figure out how to use the data:post.snippet function in blogger to bypass the Settings > Search preferences > Meta tags > Description or post Search Description that is being used as the variable for metaDescription.

The snippet function would be a great way to set the description for facebook and twitter.

Is there anyway to pickup the snippet as a data:blog variable?

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription != &quot;&quot;'>
<meta expr:content='data:post.snippet' property='og:description'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.snippet' name='twitter:description'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' itemprop='description'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='description'/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `data:post.snippet` works only in `<b:widget type='Blog'>...</b:widget>` section.

Comment: how to get the post body content from anywhere in the HTML page?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira What kind of content?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's bit too late to answer this, but since I was also searching a solution for same and have found the one working, here it is.
Post the following code within the `<head>` section of your blogger template:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
  <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='og:description'/>
</b:if>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and found that the data:post.snippet denotes the meta description for a post.
Provided you have filled the Text box in the Search description while writing the blog post.

Comment: This is unfortunately incorrect; the post.snippet is the first 140 characters of the post body, not the meta description.

The metaDescription data will show the blog's meta description when on index page types, or will show the individual post's search description when on item pages, but you can not get the item search description when on index page types.

Answer (score 0):

Blogger automatically assigns snippet of post to meta description in `<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>` by turning off description setting of blog.

Settings -> Search preferences -> Meta tags -> Description -> Enable search description? -> No

[image]
Reference: https://fulltechhelp.com/add-meta-tags-to-individual-blogger-posts/

Answer (score 0):

This code Should work:

```
&lt;meta content=&quot;<div class='item-snippet'><data:post.snippet/></div>&quot; name=&#39;Description&#39;/&gt;
```

must place avobe this line : `<data:postLabelsLabel/>`