# How do I use data:post.snippet to override my blog's meta description for individual posts?

Tags: blogger

I've tweaked my template multiple times to try to make this work, but I can't seem to find a solution. Since I don't post with individual search descriptions, every post's meta description just uses the blog's main meta description each time. So is there a way to override this and at least get a meta description from the data:post.snippet variable? Someone also asked a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280312/blogger-datapost-snippet-to-replace-datablog-metadescription-for-descripti) a few years ago, but there was never a solution for it.

I currently have these codes that have the metaDescription variable. First, I added this manually in the head:

```
<!-- Open Graph Meta Tags BEGIN -->
     <b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
          <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>
        </b:if>
```

And this is at the very top of the body:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
          <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' itemprop='description'/>
        </b:if>
```

And lastly, this is in post code in the body. So do I have to tweak this code in the post includable?

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription == &quot;&quot;'>
        <!-- Then use the post body as the schema.org description,
        for good G+/FB snippeting. -->
        <div class='post-body entry-content' expr:id='&quot;post-body-&quot; + data:post.id' itemprop='description articleBody'>
            <data:post.body/>
            <div style='clear: both;' />
            <!-- clear for photos floats -->
        </div>
        <b:else/>
        <div class='post-body entry-content' expr:id='&quot;post-body-&quot; + data:post.id' itemprop='articleBody'>
            <data:post.body/>
            <div style='clear: both;' />
            <!-- clear for photos floats -->
        </div>
```

What's interesting is I get the post's intro in my Twitter card's meta description when I put this at the top of the post code, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='twitter:description' />
    <b:else/>
    <meta expr:content='data:post.snippet' name='twitter:description' />
</b:if>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: There's no solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, `data:post.snippet` would only work inside the Blog type widget (`<b:widget type='Blog' id="somename">`).

In addition, that type of widget should only appear inside the section (`<b:section>`) tag which is not allowed inside HTML's `head` tags, else, this error should appear:

> b:section should not appear inside of head

**UPDATE:**
You can probably add these lines if you're bothered by this description issue:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription != &quot;&quot;'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>
<b:else/>
    <meta content='[INSERT A DESCRIPTION HERE]' property='og:description'/>
<b:if>
```

You can check this for a detailed description: [Adding Open Graph Meta Tags to Blogger Blogs](http://www.ajibanda.com/2012/11/adding-open-graph-meta-tags-to-blogspot.html)

Comment: Yeah, I thought I could override the index's meta description in the post id of the blog widget with data:post.snippet, but I still got the index's metadescription. I guess I should also ask if having post.snippet as metadescription would positively or negatively affect google's search results, or have no effect at all.

Comment: I'm wondering if I should delete the metadescription I have in my settings and put all of these metadescriptions in the html manually.

Comment: Not the cleanest solution but if you are bothered by this, you can check my updated answer. It is based on the template I've created years ago (still using now). As far as I know, playing with blogger's meta tags is pretty much limited so you need to find some workaround.

Comment: Thanks. I think I couldn't get any of my tags to work because I had the meta description enabled in my settings. It would override every tag I had in the head/body/post because I didn't have any search descriptions in posts.  So I unchecked that button and everything I put in manually worked, at least in my new blog with the Emporio template. I have to try this on all of my other blogs.